# Register Load Event to every form from "Application"

Tags: c#, winforms

There is `Load` event and i can do something like

```
 (new Form1()).Load +=
```

But, could i register a event to every form in my project from Application Domain? Is there an event like "OnFormOpen"?

Answer (score 1):

To register an event to every form in the project would require that you have instances of the forms created. Then you need to assign a delegate to the Load event of each form instance.

Assigning the Load event to the type itself is not possible, an instance of the type is required to assign the handler to the Load event. A part of the code could be included in the constructor to register the load event every time a form instance is created.

Here is a code snippet of a project containing 3 form classes (Form1 (startup form), Form2, Form3).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadEventRegister loadEventRegister = new LoadEventRegister();
        Form[] formInstances = new Form[] {new Form2(), new Form3()};
        loadEventRegister.RegisterLoadOnForms(formInstances);

        foreach (Form formInstance in formInstances)
        {
            formInstance.Show();
        }
    }
}

public class LoadEventRegister
{
    public void RegisterLoadOnForms(IEnumerable<Form> formInstances)
    {
        foreach (Form formInstance in formInstances)
        {
            EventInfo eventInfo = formInstance.GetType().GetEvent("Load");
            Type eventHandlerType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;

            MethodInfo eventHandler = this.GetType().GetMethod("Generic_Load");

            Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventHandlerType, this, eventHandler);
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(formInstance, d);
        }
    }

    public void Generic_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCustomLoad();
    }

    private void MyCustomLoad()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as an aside, you can capture every assembly loaded into your AppDomain by hooking into this event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found something very interesting to watch form actives. Refer to the [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/aeh.aspx), e.g.:

```
public class ApplicationEventHandler
{
    MessageFilterImp filter;

    public void Init()
    {
        filter = new MessageFilterImp();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(filter);
    }
}  

internal class MessageFilterImp : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        FormCollection forms = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach (Form form in forms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---" + System.DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine(form.Name);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```